# Sudden appearance of a -15 reputation loss on one of my old answers

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

Regarding [What does negative time mean or what does it show?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571149/), this morning my answer got a 15 points reputation loss. what happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer got [unaccepted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by OP.

Comment: wish I knew why. I though it was a good one...

Comment: @nielsnielsen You managed to reach 53.6k rep without learning about the reputation tab on your profile, or having an answer get unaccepted in the past? That's very impressive!

Comment: @user1271772, are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @niels how so? I've had tonnes of my answers get "unanswered" throughout the network, yet don't have more than 20k on any one site. Your answers must have been very good (I haven't looked at them yet, but if they've *all*  survived this long without ever getting preferred by a newer answer, It's impressive!)

Comment: @user1271772, Some of the high earners here have a disparaging attitude about those like me who do not know all the ins, outs, and features of the SE sites. In that regard I am woefully ignorant, and I guess I am lucky to have had only one accepted answer get unaccepted. BTW much of my current "earnings" come from old answers getting upvotes so I am lucky in this way as well. I should be counting my blessings!